# Purpose of WINHTTP_QUERY_URI in WinHTTP?

Tags: c++, winapi, winhttp

What HTTP header exactly can be queried using `WINHTTP_QUERY_URI` flag with [WinHttpQueryHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102.aspx) function? After reading its description I was under impression this flag was supposed to be used to get the URI of the request specified in [WinHttpOpenRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384099.aspx) function. Yet the following program gives me an error code 12019 `ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE` (and 12150 `ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND` if I uncomment two commented lines).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")
int main()
{
    HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(nullptr, WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"www.ietf.org", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);
    HINTERNET hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", L"/rfc/rfc2616.txt", nullptr, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, nullptr, 0);

    //WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
    //WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, 0);

    wchar_t url[1024] = {};
    DWORD url_size = sizeof(url);
    auto success = WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_URI, WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, url, &url_size, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
    auto error_code = GetLastError();
    wprintf(L"success=%d error_code=%u url=%s", success, error_code, url);

    WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
}
```

P.S. Yes, I know I can get request URI using `WinHttpQueryOption` and `WINHTTP_OPTION_URL`, no need to point that out.

EDIT. Adding `WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS` flag as per Captain Obvlious answer below (which totally makes sense *if* `WINHTTP_QUERY_URI` was indeed supposed to return request URI) did not make much difference: now with or without `WinHttpSendRequest` and `WinHttpReceiveResponse` calls `WinHttpQueryHeaders` function produces error code 12150 `ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: How did you solve the problemm... I am having the exact same problem.. I am trying to download a file through ssl and exactly confronting the same issues on the answer and the OP. what to do? can you please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59730223/receiving-12030-at-winhttpreceiveresponse

Comment: no i think i dont receive 12030 as much but im receving the same errors as you

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the response headers of the request which do not contain the URI. You need to include the `WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS` modifier flag to retrieve from the request header.

```
WinHttpQueryHeaders(
    hRequest,
    WINHTTP_QUERY_URI | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS,
    WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,
    url,
    &url_size,
    WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
```

Comment: Good catch, yet adding this flag does not solve the problem - now instead of error code 12019 I am getting error code 12150. Still, I'll update my post to include `WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_REQUEST_HEADERS` flag (which I totally forgot about).

Comment: AFAIK `WinHttpSendRequest` and `WinHttpReceiveResponse` still have to be called.

Comment: How to fix this ??